# How do i fix this JSON.parse error on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to do I fix this Node.js error.

```
const express=express();
const app=express();
const fs=require("fs");
const movies=JSON.parse=fs.readFileSync("movies.json", "utf-8"); // this line of code returns error.
app.get("/api/vi/movies", (req, res)=>{
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success", 
      data: {
        movies: movies
      }
    })
})
app.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", ()=>{
console.log("Connecting ...");
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xozux.png)

All the code has been written above.

Comment: What error? All I see is some code.

Comment: why are you assigning a value to `JSON.parse=`

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:
`const movies=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("movies.json", "utf-8"));`
instead of

`const movies=JSON.parse=fs.readFileSync("movies.json", "utf-8");`?

For future reference, you should probably put your error in the post instead of linking to elsewhere.

Comment: I'm sure of the codes I wrote.

Comment: @Codes Why? It doesn’t work, and you’re overwriting `JSON.parse` guaranteeing it’ll never work again, too.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1):

Parse the data into Json.parse(), which returns from the fs.readFileSync() method.

```
const express=express();
const app=express();
const fs=require("fs");
const movies=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("movies.json", "utf-8"));
app.get("/api/vi/movies", (req, res)=>{
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success", 
      data: {
        movies: movies
      }
    })
})
app.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", ()=>{
console.log("Connecting ...");
});
```